# Is it possible to ignore varchar length when setting foreign key between tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

There are two tables in my SQL Server 2008.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (
  field1 varchar(20) not null,
  field2 int,
  CONSTRAINT PK_TABLE1 PRIMARY KEY (field1)
)

CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (
  Id int,
  t1 varchar(10) not null
  t2 ntext
    CONSTRAINT PK_TABLE2 PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

Now I want to build a foreign key on table2 with below command :

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE2  
ADD CONSTRAINT TABLE2_FK 
FOREIGN KEY (t1) REFERENCES TABLE1 (field1) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

SQL Server responds that the foreign key in `Table2` is different from the column `field1` in `Table1` in length.

Is it possible to ask SQL Server to ignore the validation of length of foreign key ?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: **No**, the column must be of the same property: data type, length, etc...

Comment: Also note: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258255%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) page on `CREATE TABLE`, which includes a section about foreign keys:

> The REFERENCES clause of a table-level FOREIGN KEY constraint must
>   have the same number of reference columns as the number of columns in
>   the constraint column list. **The data type of each reference column
>   must also be the same as the corresponding column in the column list.**

Of course, you can make a computed column that casts the `VARCHAR(10)` to a `VARCHAR(20)` and then set the foreign key.